# Counting word occurrences in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search, count

I'm doing this little exercise where I'm trying to count the amount of `word` occurrences in my string `theSentence`.

```
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";
let arr= theSentence.split(' ');

function findWord(word, arr){
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] === word){
            return count++;
        }
    }
    return console.log(word +": " + count);
}
```

My function is as follows

```
findWord(/fox/i, theSentence);
```

My expected output was supposed to be `fox: 2`

But my actual out puts was `/fox/i: 0`

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong? 
My goal is to repeat this function so it reads `the`, `fox`, and `brown`

Any pointers? 
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You have several syntax problems in your code

- **`/fox/i === arr[i]`** will never turns out to be true. because **`/fox/i`** is regex and **`arr[i]`** is having primitive strings.
- return statement before **`count`** dosen't make any sense.
- You're splitting **`theSentence`** outside of function and storing in arr, but in your function call you're passing **`theSentence`** only where it should be **`arr`** or use split inside function

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";

function findWord(word, arr){
    arr= theSentence.split(' ');
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(word.test(arr[i])){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return console.log(word +": " + count);
}

findWord(/fox/i, theSentence);
```

Comment: I'm testing it on node and the `/gi` reg expression flag wasn't rendering properly, but your correction works when I use the '/i' regex.  
Why did you at the `/g` to the reg expressions?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Squirtle `g` is a global flag used when you need to match more than one occurrences. but in this case it is not needed, my bad i placed it mistakenly,i already removed it

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems:

1. You are using `return count++` which will stop the further execution of function.Should remove `return`
2. You are comparing `RegExp()` to a `string` instead you should use `test()` method of `RegExp()`
3. You should `return console.log(...)` it will return `undefined`. You can return the value and then log it.

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep fox";
let arr= theSentence.split(' ');
function findWord(word, arr){
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(word.test(arr[i])){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return word +": " + count
}
console.log(findWord(/fox/i, arr));
```

A better way to that is using [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and `g` flag in `Regex`. If you want to match the whole word `fox` use `/fox ?/gi` as regex. If you want to match it from inside word use `/fox/gi`

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";
function findWord(word, str){
    return word + ": " + str.match(word).length
}
console.log(findWord(/fox/gi, theSentence));
```

Comment: The last code is wrong. just add `fox` at the end of see the result. i guess it's a typo an extra space

Comment: You are right. Any suggestion for fix?

Comment: You can add an alternation `/fox ?/gi`

Comment: @Code Maniac thanks it worked. But I don't think OP want to check for only whole words.

Comment: If you use match than you need to use either word boundaries `(\b)` or the one you have written now

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use filter to search the word in the array and return the count

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";
let arr= theSentence.split(' ');

function findWord(word, arr){
    let count = 0;
    count=arr.filter(e=>e.toLowerCase()==word.toLowerCase()).length
    return word +": " + count;
}

console.log(findWord('the',arr))
```

Comment: It keeps returning `1` when the expected outcome is `2`

Comment: Check the edits

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is named `arr`, which sounds like you meant to pass an array - if that's what you wanted, pass `arr` instead of  `theSentence`:

`/fox/i` is a regular expression, which is an object, not a primitive - it will never be `===` to anything else. Call `.test` on each word in the array, on the regular expression, and increment `count` with `count++`, and *don't return inside the loop* - if you `return`, the function will terminate immediately. (you want it to iterate over *all* words in the array)

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";
let arr= theSentence.split(' ');

function findWord(word, arr){
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(word.test(arr[i])){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return console.log(word +": " + count);
}
findWord(/fox/i, arr);
```

You might consider using the pattern

```
/\bfox\b/i
```

instead - this will match the number of times `fox` exists in the input, case-insensitive, with a word boundary on each side.

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";

function findWord(pattern, sentence){
  const count = sentence.match(pattern).length;
  return console.log(pattern +": " + count);
}
findWord(/\bfox\b/gi, theSentence);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing Regex so use with `pattern.test(str)` .And i could rewrite code with simple format

```js
const theSentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog, who thinks the world is flat and the sky\'s blue. The brown fox then goes to sleep";


function findWord(word, arr){
   arr= arr.split(' ');
   return arr.filter(a=> word.test(a)).length
}

console.log(findWord(/fox/i, theSentence));
console.log(findWord(/The/i, theSentence));
```

Comment: There's a typo. i guess you meant `pattern.test(str)` not `pattern.text(str)`